# Spring cloud streams could not autowire Source.class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am learning Spring Cloud Streams from scratch.

I tried to create a Source application like this:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source; //etc
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@CrossOrigin
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class StreamsProducerApplication {

    @Autowired
    Source source;

    @GetMapping(value="/send/{message}")
    public void sendMessage(@PathVariable String message){
        if(message != null){

     source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StreamsProducerApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

However, I get error hint from Intellij IDEA at "Source source;" saying "Could not autowire. No beans of 'Source' type found.

I can understand that Source is a interface from where I import, but the spring official website says "Spring Cloud Stream creates an implementation of the interface for you. You can use this in the application by autowiring it" https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

So how did I do this wrong? Thank you.

Comment: did you try to run your app?

Comment: it is just an IDE false alarm

Comment: I have the same issue. The Source class is not autowired in runtime and thats resulting in error

Answer (score 2):

It is just the Intellij IDEA doesn't know that `@EnableBinding(Source.class)` is going to be a bean at runtime. There is just on such a bean definition, so tooling fails to determine what to inject in that `@Autowired`.

Otherwise your code is fully good and you just need to run it and play with whatever you expect from that code.

Comment: I have the same issue, I tried running the app(I use a constructor based injection) and I got the error in the runtime. What to do in this case?

Comment: `Parameter 0 of constructor in __ required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source' in your configuration.`

Comment: The question you are commenting is a bit out-of-date. Consider to raise a new SO thread with more relevant context.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an IDE false alert.
You can suppress this error in IDE by adding

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
```