# org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source can't be autowired

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I was toying around Spring Cloud Streams and encountered this problem.
My question looks very alike to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497582/spring-cloud-streams-could-not-autowire-source-class/53504449?noredirect=1#comment105694835_53504449), the gist is here:

> I get error hint from Intellij IDEA at "Source source;" saying "Could
>   not autowire. No beans of 'Source' type found.

As follow up here are the updated [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-stream.html#_destination_bindings):

> Aside from generating channels for each binding and registering them
>   as Spring beans, for each bound interface, Spring Cloud Stream
>   generates a bean that implements the interface.

But there is a small but crucial difference, I can't actually run this code and it fails in the startup with the following error in the logs(I use constructor based injection, but the error doesn't go away even if I change the type of injection as well as IntelliJ's error hint);

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in ____(my class) required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source' in your configuration.
```

My main class in the root of the project:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My service, where I try auto wiring the Source bean:
[image]

Parent dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-cloud-stream.version>Horsham.SR1</spring-cloud-stream.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-stream.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Why does it happen and how to fix?

Comment: Did you try it with other IDE? and what `Source` are you using? please let me know what full path is....

Comment: No, I didn't try with other IDE though this hardly has something to do with an IDE. The full path to Source is written in the title of this question.

Comment: Ok, so are you missing `@EnableBinding(Source.class)` ? I tried to following your question, then I checked if I enable this binding I don't have any error

Comment: Thanks, this is correct answer yet the dev of Spring Cloud Stream itself has actually answered, so your comment bears no value anymore. I will delete my comments shortly and suggest you doing so as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to inject `Source.class` while enabling the binding for the `Processor.class`. You need to change `@EnableBinding(Processor.class)` to `@EnableBinding(Source.class)`

<sub>**On a sidenote, since you are just starting with spring-cloud-stream might as well start with the currently latest version which is [Horsham.SR1 (3.0.1.RELEASE)](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/) and is part of Hoxton.SR1 spring-cloud train.
The main point though is that we are moving away from annotation based configuration and although what you are trying to accomplish seems like a simple miss-configuration problem on your end that we can help you to fix, why not jus switch to a much simpler functional model.
Since you're dealing with source at the moment [here is the relevant section](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function)**.</sub>

Comment: I actually use the very latest version of release trains for both spring_cloud and spring_cloud_stream, I updated the question with the dependencies. Thanks for pointing out that you are creating a functional model, looks really promising and modern, I will use this model, still the issue remains and I am keen to fix it if it's possible.

Comment: Your issue is because you enabling `Processor.class` but trying to inject `Source`. Change to `@EnableBinding(Source.class)`. That said the fact that you have this issue is the very reason why we;'re moving away from annotation-based model. It's not promising, it's already here and as you can see we removed most of the references to annotations you are using from the new docs.

Comment: In other words if you are a new user of Spring Cloud Stream you effectively started with deprecated API.

Comment: Please, elaborate more in your answer about deprecated API because currently I don't seen any signs that it's deprecated anywhere if we don't take into account the advice in docs to not use an annotation-based approach. There is a bunch of tutorials and showcases out there that don't use the functional model as an example but this one instead so it will be perfect if there was a canonical answer for this type of concern for people to come. Also add this to answer, please `Your issue is because you enabling Processor.class but trying to inject Source. Change to @EnableBinding(Source.class)`.

Comment: I am sorry, actually it's stated that it's legacy in the docs, then please could you add, please, this info to your answer as well as the actual answer to this very question(`Your issue is because you enabling Processor.class but trying to inject Source. Change to @EnableBinding(Source.class)`)